# build non-stub version of android.jar

Tags: android, build

The android.jar found in android-sdk is simply a stub. All methods will throw a runtime exception "stub"! 
Do anyone know how to get a non-stub version of android.jar? Or how to build one from the android source code (not android OS source code, I mean Android library code)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What are you trying to do? Framework jars depend on native code, so even if you built one, you won't be able to use it on your computer.

Comment: I need it for analyzing some android code. I guess I can ignore native functions.

Comment: Analyzing how? Bytecode? If you don't need to actually run the code, get Android source code and build it. Jars will be output as intermediary files in `out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES`

Comment: Great. I found it in the framework_intermediates folder under your suggested path :) thank you very much!